# Select several rows and plot two columns in python from a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

I have a CSV with 5 columns and 36 rows. The first column has a name and the second and third have two magnitudes I want on the X (wavelength) and Y (reflectance) axis. I want to be able to select different rows and plot their wavelength vs reflectance but I don't know how to select two columns for any given row. The csv has the following format:

```
Name,_xx,_yy,Source,Spectometer

Seawater_open_ocean,"[205,213,...]","[0.0360,0.0360,...]",UGSG,BECK
```

I have only written this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x=[]
y=[]

df = pd.read_csv('albedos.csv')
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

for row in df:
    x.append((row[2]))
    y.append((row[3]))

print(df.loc[['Dry_sand','Wet_sand','Old_road']])

plt.plot(x,y, marker='o')

plt.title('Spectrum')

plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
plt.ylabel('Reflectance')

plt.show()
```

I don't know how make it select the _xx and _yy columns for each indexed element and plot it. I'm very new to programming so maybe this is very easy but haven't found this specific issue solved around here. I want it to look similiar to this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDvxj.png)

Answer (score 1):

- your sample data is short of building an example... have synthesized some
- the most import step is converting lists encoded as strings to actual lists using `apply(json.loads)`
- given you already `set_index()` use this in `.loc[]` to identify your co-ordinates
- switched to creating a figure and axis,  then add each line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import io, json

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Name,_xx,_yy,Source,Spectometer
Dry_sand,"[190,193]","[0.0360,0.0370]",UGSG,BECK
Seawater_open_ocean,"[205,213]","[0.0360,0.0360]",UGSG,BECK"""), sep=",")

df["_xx"] = df["_xx"].apply(json.loads)
df["_yy"] = df["_yy"].apply(json.loads)
df.set_index("Name", inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[4,4])

# plot two lines... array specifies keys
for l in ["Seawater_open_ocean", "Dry_sand"]:
    ax.plot(df.loc[l,"_xx"], df.loc[l,"_yy"])

ax.set_title('Spectrum')
ax.set_xlabel('Wavelength')
ax.set_ylabel('Reflectance')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your plotting task is made difficult by the structure of your dataframe.

I suggest that you start by telling `read_csv` that it should evaluate the strings in `_xx` and `_yy` as native lists:

```py
 df = pd.read_csv('albedos.csv', converters={'_xx': eval, '_yy':eval})
```

Let's say that there is only one row in this dataframe:

```
                  Name         _xx             _yy Source Spectometer
0  Seawater_open_ocean  [205, 213]  [0.036, 0.036]   UGSG        BECK
```

You can expand `_xx` and `_yy` like this:

```py
exploded_df = df[['Name', '_xx', '_yy']].set_index(['Name']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

and get

```
                  Name  _xx    _yy
0  Seawater_open_ocean  205  0.036
1  Seawater_open_ocean  213  0.036
```

I assume that from there you won't have any difficulty in plotting data by filtering for each name.